# Array - find the number that is repeated most frequently

Tags: c#

I'm trying to know the number that is most present in one array.

Example:

```
8 4 3 8 4 4 1 5
```

In this case, I want the program to tell me the number is 4.

This is what I've written so far, but the `console.Writeline` returns an error system.32.

Can you help ?

```
int[] moda = new int[21];

for (int j = 0; j < avaliacoes.Length; j++)
{
    int avaliacao = avaliacoes[j];

    moda[avaliacao] = moda[avaliacao] + 1;
}

Console.WriteLine("\nA moda é{0}: ", moda);
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping with some ordering on group size should get the job done.

To summarize what I am doing I am grouping the array by there values, I then Emit that group into an anonymous type that will hold the key as well as the group count. Third I order by descending so we order or enumerable from high value to low, which will allow me to say the first element in the enumeration must be the top value (if not equal to the top value).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new[] { 8, 4, 3, 8, 4, 4, 1, 5 };
        var mostPresent = a
            .GroupBy(e => e)
            .Select(e => new { Key = e.Key, Count = e.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.Count)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(mostPresent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many methods for doing that, here is one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create array
        const int arrLength = 10;
        int[] mainArray = new int[arrLength];

        // Fill array with random numbers
        Random randNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.Length; i++)
        {
            mainArray[i] = randNum.Next(10);
        }


        // Create a dictionary for counting
        Dictionary<int, int> countDic = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var currentNumber in mainArray)
        {
            // If the current number has appeared before increase the count for that number
            if (countDic.TryGetValue(currentNumber, out int _))
            {
                countDic[currentNumber]++;
            }

            // If it's first time current number has appeared set its count as one
            else
            {
                countDic.Add(currentNumber, 1);
            }
        }

        // Print frequency of numbers
        foreach (var num in countDic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{num.Key} appears {num.Value} times in the array!");
        }

        // Print the number which appears the most in the array
        int maxNum = countDic.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Value > y.Value ? x : y).Key;
        Console.WriteLine(maxNum);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Ask me if there is anything that you can not understand in the solution

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily with LINQ. I'll explain what happens below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> ints = new List<int> { 8, 4, 3, 8, 4, 4, 1, 5 };


            var query = from i1 in ints
                        select new
                        {
                            number = i1,
                            count = ints.Where(i2 => i2 == i1).Count()
                        };

            var most = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.count).First().number;


            Console.WriteLine($"Number: {most}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

- In the first query I iterate over all ints in the list and create an anonymous object with 2 properties 'number' and 'count'. The count contains the amount of ints in the list with the number of the first iteration.
- In the second line the 'most'is selected by ordering the anonymous types in descending order on 'count' and taking the First item of that result. If you have more numbers in your array with the same number of entries you will get only the first one. So if '4' and 5' both are present 4 times it is not guaranteed which result you will get. It could be '4' but just as well '5'.